# Getting the same result at np.gradient with pytorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch and I want to calculate the gradient of an image (nrows,ncolumns).  However, torch.grad returns None.  I don't want to backpropagate this gradient, I just want it on the initial image, since I'm implementing the demons algorithm.  How can I get the same type of return as np.gradient()?

Comment: Can you add some reference code you are using?

Comment: Do you mean evaluating the gradiant on one sample? Also, share your code please.